# How do I make an async call to an MVC Controller from Razor Pages rendered screen

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm using Razor Pages but I need to make an async call to an MVC controller so I can set a session variable and persist a user setting to the database. This is a cross cutting concern that applies to all pages. I don't see any way to have a super class to the Razor Pages the way you can with a parent controller so this seemed like an acceptable work around. I am getting an HTTP 405 response however, which means the web server recognizes the route but is disallowing it.

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("Default/UpdateSelectedPermit/{id}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateSelectedPermit(string id)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Permit", id);
        return Json("success");
    }
}
```

Here's the front end:

```
 $("#permitsSelect").on('change', function (e) {
    console.log('Permit selection change: ' + $(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'Default/UpdateSelectedPermit/' + $(this).val(),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
});
```

Comment: You are doing a `POST` to a controller action with `GET` defined. What happens if you change your ajax to a `GET` instead? 405 error means `Method not allowed` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Comment: Ah, of course. I should have seen that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to `POST` to a controller action that is setup as a `GET` with `HttpGet`. You can change the ajax to a `GET`, or change the controller to an `HttpPost`

405 Error means `Method Not Allowed` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: 'Default/UpdateSelectedPermit/' + $(this).val(),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```